# facebook login without dialog in wp7

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

Several WP7 apps (like the official FB application) provide their own login dialog and after filling it you get connected to facebook.
Further you are automatically logged in when you call the application later.

In general it's no problem to store the credentials encrypted on the device.

My question - has anyone an idea how to achive what the "offical FB app" does?
I searche around - but found nothing more then "must use the dialog / there is no other way...".

But for sure there is a way - since apps do this.

Answer (score 2):

The "official fb app" also requires authentication.

the "Built in facebook support" works by connecting your LiveID to your facebook, and you still gave it your credentails when you connected it the first time.

There is nothing that exposes the "built in" credentials for any of the accounts (twitter, linked in, etc)

*Can you imagine what would happen if ANY app could just automatically log in to any of those apps and do whatever they want?*

Comment: I guess you got me wrong...
Of course ONCE there is somehow a confirmation for an application to allow FB access.
For an example FIM (which doesn't link LiveID or so) allows you

either to "connect through facebook" which brings the normal dialogs. Or you can use "login". In this case you are (by the application) prompted for username and password.
After that there are 2 possibilities. Either (never been there) you get the "confirm app" dialog. Or (if you ever accepted this app - even from a different device) you get silently logged in.
But you NEVER see the FB login dialog!!

Comment: I investigated a little - and one try brought me in the right direction....
If you give FIM wrong credentials you'll see the FB "second login try" dialog.
So I guess they just hide the normal dialog and "feed it" with the credentials you enter in the application.